# Stripe to MemberPress Webhook Error: Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1, 500 Error

Tags: stripe-payments, memberpress

Payments are processing in Stripe, but the webhook back to MemberPress that lets it know that the subscription renewed are failing. Webhooks look to be identical, and not in Test mode. Just not getting a lot of info back on the error.

Should I set up listeners?

```
{
  "id": "evt_1Kvpj1KsZRmhnThq31q4z2z5",
  "object": "event",
  "api_version": "2019-09-09",
  "created": 1651699631,
  "data": {
    "object": {
      "id": "in_1KowZdKsZRmhnThqHCHU9Ogc",
      "object": "invoice",
      "account_country": "US",
      "account_name": "xxx",
      "account_tax_ids": null,
      "amount_due": 2000,
      "amount_paid": 0,
      "amount_remaining": 2000,
      "application": "ca_Frz23gAnQWismBJBCaDbG8q329v7pYgP",
      "application_fee_amount": null,
      "attempt_count": 4,
      "attempted": true,
      "auto_advance": true,
      "automatic_tax": {
        "enabled": false,
        "status": null
      },
      "billing_reason": "subscription_cycle",
      "charge": "ch_3KoxXVKsZRmhnThq1BpxfrRH",
      "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
      "created": 1650057661,
      "currency": "usd",
      "custom_fields": null,
      "customer": "cus_JJF66CIpIHgY71",
      "customer_address": null,
      "customer_email": "xxx",
      "customer_name": "xxx",
      "customer_phone": null,
      "customer_shipping": null,
      "customer_tax_exempt": "none",
      "customer_tax_ids": [
      ],
      "default_payment_method": null,
      "default_source": null,
      "default_tax_rates": [
      ],
      "description": null,
      "discount": null,
      "discounts": [
      ],
      "due_date": null,
      "ending_balance": 0,
      "footer": null,
      "hosted_invoice_url": "xxx",
      "invoice_pdf": "xxx",
      "last_finalization_error": null,
      "lines": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "sli_1098abKsZRmhnThqaebb3d27",
            "object": "line_item",
            "amount": 2000,
            "currency": "usd",
            "description": "1 × Annual Membership (at $20.00 / year)",
            "discount_amounts": [
            ],
            "discountable": true,
            "discounts": [
            ],
            "livemode": true,
            "metadata": {
              "platform": "MemberPress Connect xxx",
              "transaction_id": "127",
              "site_url": "xxx",
              "ip_address": "xxx"
            },
            "period": {
              "end": 1681593637,
              "start": 1650057637
            },
            "plan": {
              "id": "plan_I8rke8iYhwpjp0",
              "object": "plan",
              "active": true,
              "aggregate_usage": null,
              "amount": 2000,
              "amount_decimal": "2000",
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1601828701,
              "currency": "usd",
              "interval": "year",
              "interval_count": 1,
              "livemode": true,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "prod_I8rkHCACiVHgM3",
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_usage": null,
              "trial_period_days": null,
              "usage_type": "licensed",
              "tiers": null
            },
            "price": {
              "id": "plan_I8rke8iYhwpjp0",
              "object": "price",
              "active": true,
              "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
              "created": 1601828701,
              "currency": "usd",
              "livemode": true,
              "lookup_key": null,
              "metadata": {
              },
              "nickname": null,
              "product": "prod_I8rkHCACiVHgM3",
              "recurring": {
                "aggregate_usage": null,
                "interval": "year",
                "interval_count": 1,
                "trial_period_days": null,
                "usage_type": "licensed"
              },
              "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
              "tiers_mode": null,
              "transform_quantity": null,
              "type": "recurring",
              "unit_amount": 2000,
              "unit_amount_decimal": "2000"
            },
            "proration": false,
            "proration_details": {
              "credited_items": null
            },
            "quantity": 1,
            "subscription": "sub_JJF69Ko1VVf8uw",
            "subscription_item": "si_JJF6gp8KXzNplv",
            "tax_amounts": [
            ],
            "tax_rates": [
            ],
            "type": "subscription",
            "unique_id": "il_1KowZdKsZRmhnThqPr3xCYcs"
          }
        ],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 1,
        "url": "/v1/invoices/in_1KowZdKsZRmhnThqHCHU9Ogc/lines"
      },
      "livemode": true,
      "metadata": {
      },
      "next_payment_attempt": 1651875994,
      "number": "5CB6E2A9-0002",
      "on_behalf_of": null,
      "paid": false,
      "paid_out_of_band": false,
      "payment_intent": "pi_3KoxXVKsZRmhnThq1Y9GWeY3",
      "payment_settings": {
        "payment_method_options": null,
        "payment_method_types": null
      },
      "period_end": 1650057637,
      "period_start": 1618521637,
      "post_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
      "pre_payment_credit_notes_amount": 0,
      "quote": null,
      "receipt_number": null,
      "starting_balance": 0,
      "statement_descriptor": null,
      "status": "open",
      "status_transitions": {
        "finalized_at": 1650061373,
        "marked_uncollectible_at": null,
        "paid_at": null,
        "voided_at": null
      },
      "subscription": "sub_JJF69Ko1VVf8uw",
      "subtotal": 2000,
      "tax": null,
      "test_clock": null,
      "total": 2000,
      "total_discount_amounts": [
      ],
      "total_tax_amounts": [
      ],
      "transfer_data": null,
      "webhooks_delivered_at": 1650057661,
      "billing": "charge_automatically",
      "tax_percent": null
    }
  },
  "livemode": true,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
  "request": {
    "id": null,
    "idempotency_key": null
  },
  "type": "invoice.payment_failed"
}
```

Comment: Do not fill your post with irrelevant content or gibberish in an attempt to bypass our quality filters. This is considered an abuse of the system. The quality warnings are there for a reason: they're intended to motivate you to add more *explanation* to your question. This is to your advantage, too, as it helps you get better answers faster. We've chosen to simply remove the irrelevant text in this case, but next time you try this, your entire post may be removed without warning.

Answer (score 1):

That `"Invalid encoding: ISO-8859-1"` error is sort of a red herring, it basically means Stripe was not able to read the response body the server sent back to it(as the server is probably returning something unparsable in that character set due to being misconfigured), so it can't show you what was sent .

It's probably not directly related to why the webhook delivery is failing. You or whomever has access to this would need to look at the server logs of your server that receives the webhook and see what it does when receiving the requset from Stripe and what errors it encountered by checking logs there and debug from that point.